# How to fix the redis cluster state, after a master and all its slaves are down?

Tags: redis

Steps:

1. Form a working cluster of 10 node with 5 master and 5 slaves
2. Kill one master with highest epoch and its corresponding slave. (e.g. :7008-Master and :7002-Slave)
3. How to fix the cluster, if the :7008 and :7002 nodes are not recoverable? (I am fine with data loss for the slots served by the crashed master)

Tried following options:

1. redis-trib.rb fix - getting "ERR Slot 13108 is already busy" (refer output below)
2. Run cluster forget for the crashed master and slave id, then execute redis-trib.rb fix - getting "[ERR] Nodes don't agree about configuration!"

I think both the above options are not working because cluster_current_epoch is greater than all the running node's cluster_my_epoch.

**How to fix the redis cluster state?**

Output:

```
Working Cluster:

root@9b1f373fcb81:/redis/redis_work#  /redis/redis-4.0.2/src/redis-cli -p 7000 cluster info | grep epoch
  cluster_current_epoch:10
  cluster_my_epoch:1
  root@9b1f373fcb81:/redis/redis_work#  /redis/redis-4.0.2/src/redis-cli -p 7001 cluster info | grep epoch
  cluster_current_epoch:10
  cluster_my_epoch:2
  root@9b1f373fcb81:/redis/redis_work#  /redis/redis-4.0.2/src/redis-cli -p 7002 cluster info | grep epoch
  cluster_current_epoch:10
  cluster_my_epoch:10
  root@9b1f373fcb81:/redis/redis_work#  /redis/redis-4.0.2/src/redis-cli -p 7003 cluster info | grep epoch
  cluster_current_epoch:10
  cluster_my_epoch:6
  root@9b1f373fcb81:/redis/redis_work#  /redis/redis-4.0.2/src/redis-cli -p 7004 cluster info | grep epoch
  cluster_current_epoch:10
  cluster_my_epoch:7
  root@9b1f373fcb81:/redis/redis_work#  /redis/redis-4.0.2/src/redis-cli -p 7005 cluster info | grep epoch
  cluster_current_epoch:10
  cluster_my_epoch:1
  root@9b1f373fcb81:/redis/redis_work#  /redis/redis-4.0.2/src/redis-cli -p 7006 cluster info | grep epoch
  cluster_current_epoch:10
  cluster_my_epoch:2
  root@9b1f373fcb81:/redis/redis_work#  /redis/redis-4.0.2/src/redis-cli -p 7007 cluster info | grep epoch
  cluster_current_epoch:10
  cluster_my_epoch:7
  root@9b1f373fcb81:/redis/redis_work#  /redis/redis-4.0.2/src/redis-cli -p 7008 cluster info | grep epoch
  cluster_current_epoch:10
  cluster_my_epoch:10
  root@9b1f373fcb81:/redis/redis_work#  /redis/redis-4.0.2/src/redis-cli -p 7009 cluster info | grep epoch
  cluster_current_epoch:10
  cluster_my_epoch:6
  root@9b1f373fcb81:/redis/redis_work# /redis/redis-4.0.2/src/redis-trib.rb check 127.0.0.1:7000
  >>> Performing Cluster Check (using node 127.0.0.1:7000)
  M: 1f2d3ef5b4597b460080506a2df96447dec0e0c0 127.0.0.1:7000
     slots:2185-5460 (3276 slots) master
     1 additional replica(s)
  S: 07a4e205e7116691a568fbd6ded69c61f3dc4bdf 127.0.0.1:7006
     slots: (0 slots) slave
     replicates 9aae5952143d1c54b8be887f7f144b55ac491b08
  M: b29bfac95b729e0cf8304a2d0479941818a05c15 127.0.0.1:7008
     slots:13108-16383 (3276 slots) master
     1 additional replica(s)
  S: 8904962c822402a8d8e810b44d4ca7e847a573e8 127.0.0.1:7002
     slots: (0 slots) slave
     replicates b29bfac95b729e0cf8304a2d0479941818a05c15
  M: a2dbd1143d7e354bc48f84f11c738954582a73fb 127.0.0.1:7004
     slots:0-2184,5461,6555-7646 (3278 slots) master
     1 additional replica(s)
  S: fad0764c5bcb13b6154402c0a30bea4d541a54eb 127.0.0.1:7009
     slots: (0 slots) slave
     replicates 380920c0b693f2a955ec0f7226cc2df187c82dd7
  M: 9aae5952143d1c54b8be887f7f144b55ac491b08 127.0.0.1:7001
     slots:7647-10922 (3276 slots) master
     1 additional replica(s)
  S: b1dfb1eed811b84de7f2e770dcea39c5bca23ceb 127.0.0.1:7005
     slots: (0 slots) slave
     replicates 1f2d3ef5b4597b460080506a2df96447dec0e0c0
  M: 380920c0b693f2a955ec0f7226cc2df187c82dd7 127.0.0.1:7003
     slots:5462-6554,10923-13107 (3278 slots) master
     1 additional replica(s)
  S: dfa867e8b313ca93f525cb44fe97df8c1c5260f0 127.0.0.1:7007
     slots: (0 slots) slave
     replicates a2dbd1143d7e354bc48f84f11c738954582a73fb
  [OK] All nodes agree about slots configuration.
  >>> Check for open slots...
  >>> Check slots coverage...
  [OK] All 16384 slots covered.
  root@9b1f373fcb81:/redis/redis_work# /redis/redis-4.0.2/src/redis-trib.rb info 127.0.0.1:7000
  127.0.0.1:7000 (1f2d3ef5...) -> 5979 keys | 3276 slots | 1 slaves.
  127.0.0.1:7008 (b29bfac9...) -> 6009 keys | 3276 slots | 1 slaves.
  127.0.0.1:7004 (a2dbd114...) -> 6006 keys | 3278 slots | 1 slaves.
  127.0.0.1:7001 (9aae5952...) -> 6003 keys | 3276 slots | 1 slaves.
  127.0.0.1:7003 (380920c0...) -> 6003 keys | 3278 slots | 1 slaves.
  [OK] 30000 keys in 5 masters.
  1.83 keys per slot on average.
  root@9b1f373fcb81:/redis/redis_work#

  Killed :7008 and :7002 redis nodes

  root@9b1f373fcb81:/redis/redis_work# /redis/redis-4.0.2/src/redis-trib.rb info 127.0.0.1:7000
  127.0.0.1:7000 (1f2d3ef5...) -> 5979 keys | 3276 slots | 1 slaves.
  127.0.0.1:7004 (a2dbd114...) -> 6006 keys | 3278 slots | 1 slaves.
  127.0.0.1:7001 (9aae5952...) -> 6003 keys | 3276 slots | 1 slaves.
  127.0.0.1:7003 (380920c0...) -> 6003 keys | 3278 slots | 1 slaves.
  [OK] 23991 keys in 4 masters.
  1.46 keys per slot on average.
  root@9b1f373fcb81:/redis/redis_work# /redis/redis-4.0.2/src/redis-trib.rb check 127.0.0.1:7000
  >>> Performing Cluster Check (using node 127.0.0.1:7000)
  M: 1f2d3ef5b4597b460080506a2df96447dec0e0c0 127.0.0.1:7000
     slots:2185-5460 (3276 slots) master
     1 additional replica(s)
  S: 07a4e205e7116691a568fbd6ded69c61f3dc4bdf 127.0.0.1:7006
     slots: (0 slots) slave
     replicates 9aae5952143d1c54b8be887f7f144b55ac491b08
  M: a2dbd1143d7e354bc48f84f11c738954582a73fb 127.0.0.1:7004
     slots:0-2184,5461,6555-7646 (3278 slots) master
     1 additional replica(s)
  S: fad0764c5bcb13b6154402c0a30bea4d541a54eb 127.0.0.1:7009
     slots: (0 slots) slave
     replicates 380920c0b693f2a955ec0f7226cc2df187c82dd7
  M: 9aae5952143d1c54b8be887f7f144b55ac491b08 127.0.0.1:7001
     slots:7647-10922 (3276 slots) master
     1 additional replica(s)
  S: b1dfb1eed811b84de7f2e770dcea39c5bca23ceb 127.0.0.1:7005
     slots: (0 slots) slave
     replicates 1f2d3ef5b4597b460080506a2df96447dec0e0c0
  M: 380920c0b693f2a955ec0f7226cc2df187c82dd7 127.0.0.1:7003
     slots:5462-6554,10923-13107 (3278 slots) master
     1 additional replica(s)
  S: dfa867e8b313ca93f525cb44fe97df8c1c5260f0 127.0.0.1:7007
     slots: (0 slots) slave
     replicates a2dbd1143d7e354bc48f84f11c738954582a73fb
  [OK] All nodes agree about slots configuration.
  >>> Check for open slots...
  >>> Check slots coverage...
  [ERR] Not all 16384 slots are covered by nodes.

  Trying to fix with add slots option via redis-trib


  /redis/redis-4.0.2/src/redis-trib.rb fix 127.0.0.1:7000
  ...blah_missing_slot blah_missing_slot blah_missing_slot
  ...blah_missing_slot blah_missing_slot blah_missing_slot
  58,16359,16360,16361,16362,16363,16364,16365,16366,16367,16368,16369,16370,16371,16372,16373,16374,16375,16376,16377,16378,16379,16380,16381,16382,16383
  Fix these slots by covering with a random node? (type 'yes' to accept): yes
  >>> Covering slot 13108 with 127.0.0.1:7003
  /usr/local/bundle/gems/redis-3.3.3/lib/redis/client.rb:121:in `call': ERR Slot 13108 is already busy (Redis::CommandError)
     from /usr/local/bundle/gems/redis-3.3.3/lib/redis.rb:2705:in `block in method_missing'
     from /usr/local/bundle/gems/redis-3.3.3/lib/redis.rb:58:in `block in synchronize'
     from /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.4.0/monitor.rb:214:in `mon_synchronize'
     from /usr/local/bundle/gems/redis-3.3.3/lib/redis.rb:58:in `synchronize'
     from /usr/local/bundle/gems/redis-3.3.3/lib/redis.rb:2704:in `method_missing'
     from /redis/redis-4.0.2/src/redis-trib.rb:463:in `block in fix_slots_coverage'
     from /redis/redis-4.0.2/src/redis-trib.rb:460:in `each'
     from /redis/redis-4.0.2/src/redis-trib.rb:460:in `fix_slots_coverage'
     from /redis/redis-4.0.2/src/redis-trib.rb:398:in `check_slots_coverage'
     from /redis/redis-4.0.2/src/redis-trib.rb:361:in `check_cluster'
     from /redis/redis-4.0.2/src/redis-trib.rb:1140:in `fix_cluster_cmd'
     from /redis/redis-4.0.2/src/redis-trib.rb:1700:in `<main>'
  root@9b1f373fcb81:/redis/redis_work#

  None of the running redis node's "cluster_my_epoch" equals "cluster_current_epoch"

  root@9b1f373fcb81:/redis/redis_work# /redis/redis-4.0.2/src/redis-cli -p 7000 cluster info | grep epoch
  cluster_current_epoch:10
  cluster_my_epoch:1
  root@9b1f373fcb81:/redis/redis_work# /redis/redis-4.0.2/src/redis-cli -p 7001 cluster info | grep epoch
  cluster_current_epoch:10
  cluster_my_epoch:2
  root@9b1f373fcb81:/redis/redis_work# /redis/redis-4.0.2/src/redis-cli -p 7002 cluster info | grep epoch
  Could not connect to Redis at 127.0.0.1:7002: Connection refused
  root@9b1f373fcb81:/redis/redis_work# /redis/redis-4.0.2/src/redis-cli -p 7003 cluster info | grep epoch
  cluster_current_epoch:10
  cluster_my_epoch:6
  root@9b1f373fcb81:/redis/redis_work# /redis/redis-4.0.2/src/redis-cli -p 7004 cluster info | grep epoch
  cluster_current_epoch:10
  cluster_my_epoch:7
  root@9b1f373fcb81:/redis/redis_work# /redis/redis-4.0.2/src/redis-cli -p 7005 cluster info | grep epoch
  cluster_current_epoch:10
  cluster_my_epoch:1
  root@9b1f373fcb81:/redis/redis_work# /redis/redis-4.0.2/src/redis-cli -p 7006 cluster info | grep epoch
  cluster_current_epoch:10
  cluster_my_epoch:2
  root@9b1f373fcb81:/redis/redis_work# /redis/redis-4.0.2/src/redis-cli -p 7007 cluster info | grep epoch
  cluster_current_epoch:10
  cluster_my_epoch:7
  root@9b1f373fcb81:/redis/redis_work# /redis/redis-4.0.2/src/redis-cli -p 7008 cluster info | grep epoch
  Could not connect to Redis at 127.0.0.1:7008: Connection refused
  root@9b1f373fcb81:/redis/redis_work# /redis/redis-4.0.2/src/redis-cli -p 7009 cluster info | grep epoch
  cluster_current_epoch:10
  cluster_my_epoch:6
  root@9b1f373fcb81:/redis/redis_work#

  Cluster Nodes

  root@9b1f373fcb81:/redis/redis_work# /redis/redis-4.0.2/src/redis-trib.rb call 127.0.0.1:7000 cluster nodes
  >>> Calling CLUSTER nodes
  127.0.0.1:7000: 07a4e205e7116691a568fbd6ded69c61f3dc4bdf 127.0.0.1:7006@17006 slave 9aae5952143d1c54b8be887f7f144b55ac491b08 0 1509429143161 2 connected
  b29bfac95b729e0cf8304a2d0479941818a05c15 127.0.0.1:7008@17008 master,fail - 1509428542267 1509428541654 10 disconnected 13108-16383
  8904962c822402a8d8e810b44d4ca7e847a573e8 127.0.0.1:7002@17002 slave,fail b29bfac95b729e0cf8304a2d0479941818a05c15 1509428540940 1509428539208 10 disconnected
  a2dbd1143d7e354bc48f84f11c738954582a73fb 127.0.0.1:7004@17004 master - 0 1509429144596 7 connected 0-2184 5461 6555-7646
  fad0764c5bcb13b6154402c0a30bea4d541a54eb 127.0.0.1:7009@17009 slave 380920c0b693f2a955ec0f7226cc2df187c82dd7 0 1509429144000 6 connected
  1f2d3ef5b4597b460080506a2df96447dec0e0c0 127.0.0.1:7000@17000 myself,master - 0 1509429144000 1 connected 2185-5460
  9aae5952143d1c54b8be887f7f144b55ac491b08 127.0.0.1:7001@17001 master - 0 1509429144184 2 connected 7647-10922
  b1dfb1eed811b84de7f2e770dcea39c5bca23ceb 127.0.0.1:7005@17005 slave 1f2d3ef5b4597b460080506a2df96447dec0e0c0 0 1509429143572 1 connected
  380920c0b693f2a955ec0f7226cc2df187c82dd7 127.0.0.1:7003@17003 master - 0 1509429144697 6 connected 5462-6554 10923-13107
  dfa867e8b313ca93f525cb44fe97df8c1c5260f0 127.0.0.1:7007@17007 slave a2dbd1143d7e354bc48f84f11c738954582a73fb 0 1509429145206 7 connected
  127.0.0.1:7006: b29bfac95b729e0cf8304a2d0479941818a05c15 127.0.0.1:7008@17008 master,fail - 1509428542267 1509428540000 10 disconnected 13108-16383
  a2dbd1143d7e354bc48f84f11c738954582a73fb 127.0.0.1:7004@17004 master - 0 1509429145005 7 connected 0-2184 5461 6555-7646
  9aae5952143d1c54b8be887f7f144b55ac491b08 127.0.0.1:7001@17001 master - 0 1509429144492 2 connected 7647-10922
  07a4e205e7116691a568fbd6ded69c61f3dc4bdf 127.0.0.1:7006@17006 myself,slave 9aae5952143d1c54b8be887f7f144b55ac491b08 0 1509429143000 0 connected
  380920c0b693f2a955ec0f7226cc2df187c82dd7 127.0.0.1:7003@17003 master - 0 1509429145106 6 connected 5462-6554 10923-13107
  8904962c822402a8d8e810b44d4ca7e847a573e8 127.0.0.1:7002@17002 slave,fail b29bfac95b729e0cf8304a2d0479941818a05c15 1509428540940 1509428540526 10 disconnected
  b1dfb1eed811b84de7f2e770dcea39c5bca23ceb 127.0.0.1:7005@17005 slave 1f2d3ef5b4597b460080506a2df96447dec0e0c0 0 1509429143571 1 connected
  fad0764c5bcb13b6154402c0a30bea4d541a54eb 127.0.0.1:7009@17009 slave 380920c0b693f2a955ec0f7226cc2df187c82dd7 0 1509429144000 6 connected
  dfa867e8b313ca93f525cb44fe97df8c1c5260f0 127.0.0.1:7007@17007 slave a2dbd1143d7e354bc48f84f11c738954582a73fb 0 1509429144000 7 connected
  1f2d3ef5b4597b460080506a2df96447dec0e0c0 127.0.0.1:7000@17000 master - 0 1509429145106 1 connected 2185-5460
  127.0.0.1:7004: 1f2d3ef5b4597b460080506a2df96447dec0e0c0 127.0.0.1:7000@17000 master - 0 1509429143000 1 connected 2185-5460
  fad0764c5bcb13b6154402c0a30bea4d541a54eb 127.0.0.1:7009@17009 slave 380920c0b693f2a955ec0f7226cc2df187c82dd7 0 1509429144596 6 connected
  a2dbd1143d7e354bc48f84f11c738954582a73fb 127.0.0.1:7004@17004 myself,master - 0 1509429142000 7 connected 0-2184 5461 6555-7646
  dfa867e8b313ca93f525cb44fe97df8c1c5260f0 127.0.0.1:7007@17007 slave a2dbd1143d7e354bc48f84f11c738954582a73fb 0 1509429144595 7 connected
  9aae5952143d1c54b8be887f7f144b55ac491b08 127.0.0.1:7001@17001 master - 0 1509429144698 2 connected 7647-10922
  07a4e205e7116691a568fbd6ded69c61f3dc4bdf 127.0.0.1:7006@17006 slave 9aae5952143d1c54b8be887f7f144b55ac491b08 0 1509429143571 2 connected
  8904962c822402a8d8e810b44d4ca7e847a573e8 127.0.0.1:7002@17002 slave,fail b29bfac95b729e0cf8304a2d0479941818a05c15 1509428540940 1509428539000 10 disconnected
  b29bfac95b729e0cf8304a2d0479941818a05c15 127.0.0.1:7008@17008 master,fail - 1509428542267 1509428541000 10 disconnected 13108-16383
  380920c0b693f2a955ec0f7226cc2df187c82dd7 127.0.0.1:7003@17003 master - 0 1509429144000 6 connected 5462-6554 10923-13107
  b1dfb1eed811b84de7f2e770dcea39c5bca23ceb 127.0.0.1:7005@17005 slave 1f2d3ef5b4597b460080506a2df96447dec0e0c0 0 1509429143571 1 connected
  127.0.0.1:7009: dfa867e8b313ca93f525cb44fe97df8c1c5260f0 127.0.0.1:7007@17007 slave a2dbd1143d7e354bc48f84f11c738954582a73fb 0 1509429144596 7 connected
  07a4e205e7116691a568fbd6ded69c61f3dc4bdf 127.0.0.1:7006@17006 slave 9aae5952143d1c54b8be887f7f144b55ac491b08 0 1509429143161 2 connected
  b29bfac95b729e0cf8304a2d0479941818a05c15 127.0.0.1:7008@17008 master,fail - 1509428542267 1509428541000 10 disconnected 13108-16383
  b1dfb1eed811b84de7f2e770dcea39c5bca23ceb 127.0.0.1:7005@17005 slave 1f2d3ef5b4597b460080506a2df96447dec0e0c0 0 1509429143161 1 connected
  fad0764c5bcb13b6154402c0a30bea4d541a54eb 127.0.0.1:7009@17009 myself,slave 380920c0b693f2a955ec0f7226cc2df187c82dd7 0 1509429144000 0 connected
  1f2d3ef5b4597b460080506a2df96447dec0e0c0 127.0.0.1:7000@17000 master - 0 1509429144000 1 connected 2185-5460
  8904962c822402a8d8e810b44d4ca7e847a573e8 127.0.0.1:7002@17002 slave,fail b29bfac95b729e0cf8304a2d0479941818a05c15 1509428540940 1509428539105 10 disconnected
  9aae5952143d1c54b8be887f7f144b55ac491b08 127.0.0.1:7001@17001 master - 0 1509429145106 2 connected 7647-10922
  380920c0b693f2a955ec0f7226cc2df187c82dd7 127.0.0.1:7003@17003 master - 0 1509429145206 6 connected 5462-6554 10923-13107
  a2dbd1143d7e354bc48f84f11c738954582a73fb 127.0.0.1:7004@17004 master - 0 1509429145000 7 connected 0-2184 5461 6555-7646
  127.0.0.1:7001: 07a4e205e7116691a568fbd6ded69c61f3dc4bdf 127.0.0.1:7006@17006 slave 9aae5952143d1c54b8be887f7f144b55ac491b08 0 1509429143876 2 connected
  a2dbd1143d7e354bc48f84f11c738954582a73fb 127.0.0.1:7004@17004 master - 0 1509429144000 7 connected 0-2184 5461 6555-7646
  b1dfb1eed811b84de7f2e770dcea39c5bca23ceb 127.0.0.1:7005@17005 slave 1f2d3ef5b4597b460080506a2df96447dec0e0c0 0 1509429143571 1 connected
  b29bfac95b729e0cf8304a2d0479941818a05c15 127.0.0.1:7008@17008 master,fail - 1509428542268 1509428541000 10 disconnected 13108-16383
  fad0764c5bcb13b6154402c0a30bea4d541a54eb 127.0.0.1:7009@17009 slave 380920c0b693f2a955ec0f7226cc2df187c82dd7 0 1509429145106 6 connected
  8904962c822402a8d8e810b44d4ca7e847a573e8 127.0.0.1:7002@17002 slave,fail b29bfac95b729e0cf8304a2d0479941818a05c15 1509428540940 1509428540000 10 disconnected
  9aae5952143d1c54b8be887f7f144b55ac491b08 127.0.0.1:7001@17001 myself,master - 0 1509429142000 2 connected 7647-10922
  380920c0b693f2a955ec0f7226cc2df187c82dd7 127.0.0.1:7003@17003 master - 0 1509429144596 6 connected 5462-6554 10923-13107
  dfa867e8b313ca93f525cb44fe97df8c1c5260f0 127.0.0.1:7007@17007 slave a2dbd1143d7e354bc48f84f11c738954582a73fb 0 1509429144000 7 connected
  1f2d3ef5b4597b460080506a2df96447dec0e0c0 127.0.0.1:7000@17000 master - 0 1509429144386 1 connected 2185-5460
  127.0.0.1:7005: fad0764c5bcb13b6154402c0a30bea4d541a54eb 127.0.0.1:7009@17009 slave 380920c0b693f2a955ec0f7226cc2df187c82dd7 0 1509429144596 6 connected
  9aae5952143d1c54b8be887f7f144b55ac491b08 127.0.0.1:7001@17001 master - 0 1509429145106 2 connected 7647-10922
  b1dfb1eed811b84de7f2e770dcea39c5bca23ceb 127.0.0.1:7005@17005 myself,slave 1f2d3ef5b4597b460080506a2df96447dec0e0c0 0 1509429143000 0 connected
  a2dbd1143d7e354bc48f84f11c738954582a73fb 127.0.0.1:7004@17004 master - 0 1509429144000 7 connected 0-2184 5461 6555-7646
  b29bfac95b729e0cf8304a2d0479941818a05c15 127.0.0.1:7008@17008 master,fail - 1509428542267 1509428540000 10 disconnected 13108-16383
  07a4e205e7116691a568fbd6ded69c61f3dc4bdf 127.0.0.1:7006@17006 slave 9aae5952143d1c54b8be887f7f144b55ac491b08 0 1509429143572 2 connected
  dfa867e8b313ca93f525cb44fe97df8c1c5260f0 127.0.0.1:7007@17007 slave a2dbd1143d7e354bc48f84f11c738954582a73fb 0 1509429143161 7 connected
  380920c0b693f2a955ec0f7226cc2df187c82dd7 127.0.0.1:7003@17003 master - 0 1509429143571 6 connected 5462-6554 10923-13107
  1f2d3ef5b4597b460080506a2df96447dec0e0c0 127.0.0.1:7000@17000 master - 0 1509429143000 1 connected 2185-5460
  8904962c822402a8d8e810b44d4ca7e847a573e8 127.0.0.1:7002@17002 slave,fail b29bfac95b729e0cf8304a2d0479941818a05c15 1509428540940 1509428539000 10 disconnected
  127.0.0.1:7003: b29bfac95b729e0cf8304a2d0479941818a05c15 127.0.0.1:7008@17008 master,fail - 1509428542268 1509428541554 10 disconnected 13108-16383
  fad0764c5bcb13b6154402c0a30bea4d541a54eb 127.0.0.1:7009@17009 slave 380920c0b693f2a955ec0f7226cc2df187c82dd7 0 1509429145106 6 connected
  b1dfb1eed811b84de7f2e770dcea39c5bca23ceb 127.0.0.1:7005@17005 slave 1f2d3ef5b4597b460080506a2df96447dec0e0c0 0 1509429143571 1 connected
  8904962c822402a8d8e810b44d4ca7e847a573e8 127.0.0.1:7002@17002 slave,fail b29bfac95b729e0cf8304a2d0479941818a05c15 1509428540940 1509428539000 10 disconnected
  1f2d3ef5b4597b460080506a2df96447dec0e0c0 127.0.0.1:7000@17000 master - 0 1509429144000 1 connected 2185-5460
  380920c0b693f2a955ec0f7226cc2df187c82dd7 127.0.0.1:7003@17003 myself,master - 0 1509429144000 6 connected 5462-6554 10923-13107
  dfa867e8b313ca93f525cb44fe97df8c1c5260f0 127.0.0.1:7007@17007 slave a2dbd1143d7e354bc48f84f11c738954582a73fb 0 1509429144000 7 connected
  9aae5952143d1c54b8be887f7f144b55ac491b08 127.0.0.1:7001@17001 master - 0 1509429144000 2 connected 7647-10922
  a2dbd1143d7e354bc48f84f11c738954582a73fb 127.0.0.1:7004@17004 master - 0 1509429145000 7 connected 0-2184 5461 6555-7646
  07a4e205e7116691a568fbd6ded69c61f3dc4bdf 127.0.0.1:7006@17006 slave 9aae5952143d1c54b8be887f7f144b55ac491b08 0 1509429143673 2 connected
  127.0.0.1:7007: 1f2d3ef5b4597b460080506a2df96447dec0e0c0 127.0.0.1:7000@17000 master - 0 1509429145000 1 connected 2185-5460
  a2dbd1143d7e354bc48f84f11c738954582a73fb 127.0.0.1:7004@17004 master - 0 1509429145106 7 connected 0-2184 5461 6555-7646
  b29bfac95b729e0cf8304a2d0479941818a05c15 127.0.0.1:7008@17008 master,fail - 1509428542267 1509428541758 10 disconnected 13108-16383
  fad0764c5bcb13b6154402c0a30bea4d541a54eb 127.0.0.1:7009@17009 slave 380920c0b693f2a955ec0f7226cc2df187c82dd7 0 1509429144285 6 connected
  9aae5952143d1c54b8be887f7f144b55ac491b08 127.0.0.1:7001@17001 master - 0 1509429144000 2 connected 7647-10922
  380920c0b693f2a955ec0f7226cc2df187c82dd7 127.0.0.1:7003@17003 master - 0 1509429145000 6 connected 5462-6554 10923-13107
  b1dfb1eed811b84de7f2e770dcea39c5bca23ceb 127.0.0.1:7005@17005 slave 1f2d3ef5b4597b460080506a2df96447dec0e0c0 0 1509429143263 1 connected
  dfa867e8b313ca93f525cb44fe97df8c1c5260f0 127.0.0.1:7007@17007 myself,slave a2dbd1143d7e354bc48f84f11c738954582a73fb 0 1509429144000 0 connected
  07a4e205e7116691a568fbd6ded69c61f3dc4bdf 127.0.0.1:7006@17006 slave 9aae5952143d1c54b8be887f7f144b55ac491b08 0 1509429145307 2 connected
  8904962c822402a8d8e810b44d4ca7e847a573e8 127.0.0.1:7002@17002 slave,fail b29bfac95b729e0cf8304a2d0479941818a05c15 1509428540940 1509428539000 10 disconnected
  root@9b1f373fcb81:/redis/redis_work#

  Forget the failed master and slave

  root@9b1f373fcb81:/redis/redis_work# /redis/redis-4.0.2/src/redis-trib.rb call 127.0.0.1:7000 cluster forget b29bfac95b729e0cf8304a2d0479941818a05c15
  >>> Calling CLUSTER forget b29bfac95b729e0cf8304a2d0479941818a05c15
  127.0.0.1:7000: OK
  127.0.0.1:7006: OK
  127.0.0.1:7004: OK
  127.0.0.1:7009: OK
  127.0.0.1:7001: OK
  127.0.0.1:7005: OK
  127.0.0.1:7003: OK
  127.0.0.1:7007: OK
  root@9b1f373fcb81:/redis/redis_work# /redis/redis-4.0.2/src/redis-trib.rb call 127.0.0.1:7000 cluster forget 8904962c822402a8d8e810b44d4ca7e847a573e8
  >>> Calling CLUSTER forget 8904962c822402a8d8e810b44d4ca7e847a573e8
  127.0.0.1:7000: OK
  127.0.0.1:7006: OK
  127.0.0.1:7004: OK
  127.0.0.1:7009: OK
  127.0.0.1:7001: OK
  127.0.0.1:7005: OK
  127.0.0.1:7003: OK
  127.0.0.1:7007: OK
  root@9b1f373fcb81:/redis/redis_work# /redis/redis-4.0.2/src/redis-cli -p 7000 cluster info | grep epoch
  cluster_current_epoch:10
  cluster_my_epoch:1
  root@9b1f373fcb81:/redis/redis_work# /redis/redis-4.0.2/src/redis-cli -p 7001 cluster info | grep epoch
  cluster_current_epoch:10
  cluster_my_epoch:2
  root@9b1f373fcb81:/redis/redis_work# /redis/redis-4.0.2/src/redis-cli -p 7002 cluster info | grep epoch
  Could not connect to Redis at 127.0.0.1:7002: Connection refused
  root@9b1f373fcb81:/redis/redis_work# /redis/redis-4.0.2/src/redis-cli -p 7003 cluster info | grep epoch
  cluster_current_epoch:10
  cluster_my_epoch:6
  root@9b1f373fcb81:/redis/redis_work# /redis/redis-4.0.2/src/redis-cli -p 7004 cluster info | grep epoch
  cluster_current_epoch:10
  cluster_my_epoch:7
  root@9b1f373fcb81:/redis/redis_work# /redis/redis-4.0.2/src/redis-cli -p 7005 cluster info | grep epoch
  cluster_current_epoch:10
  cluster_my_epoch:1
  root@9b1f373fcb81:/redis/redis_work# /redis/redis-4.0.2/src/redis-cli -p 7006 cluster info | grep epoch
  cluster_current_epoch:10
  cluster_my_epoch:2
  root@9b1f373fcb81:/redis/redis_work# /redis/redis-4.0.2/src/redis-cli -p 7007 cluster info | grep epoch
  cluster_current_epoch:10
  cluster_my_epoch:7
  root@9b1f373fcb81:/redis/redis_work# /redis/redis-4.0.2/src/redis-cli -p 7008 cluster info | grep epoch
  Could not connect to Redis at 127.0.0.1:7008: Connection refused
  root@9b1f373fcb81:/redis/redis_work# /redis/redis-4.0.2/src/redis-cli -p 7009 cluster info | grep epoch
  cluster_current_epoch:10
  cluster_my_epoch:6
  root@9b1f373fcb81:/redis/redis_work# /redis/redis-4.0.2/src/redis-trib.rb check 127.0.0.1:7000
  >>> Performing Cluster Check (using node 127.0.0.1:7000)
  M: 1f2d3ef5b4597b460080506a2df96447dec0e0c0 127.0.0.1:7000
     slots:2185-5460 (3276 slots) master
     1 additional replica(s)
  S: 07a4e205e7116691a568fbd6ded69c61f3dc4bdf 127.0.0.1:7006
     slots: (0 slots) slave
     replicates 9aae5952143d1c54b8be887f7f144b55ac491b08
  M: a2dbd1143d7e354bc48f84f11c738954582a73fb 127.0.0.1:7004
     slots:0-2184,5461,6555-7646 (3278 slots) master
     1 additional replica(s)
  S: fad0764c5bcb13b6154402c0a30bea4d541a54eb 127.0.0.1:7009
     slots: (0 slots) slave
     replicates 380920c0b693f2a955ec0f7226cc2df187c82dd7
  M: 9aae5952143d1c54b8be887f7f144b55ac491b08 127.0.0.1:7001
     slots:7647-10922 (3276 slots) master
     1 additional replica(s)
  S: b1dfb1eed811b84de7f2e770dcea39c5bca23ceb 127.0.0.1:7005
     slots: (0 slots) slave
     replicates 1f2d3ef5b4597b460080506a2df96447dec0e0c0
  M: 380920c0b693f2a955ec0f7226cc2df187c82dd7 127.0.0.1:7003
     slots:5462-6554,10923-13107 (3278 slots) master
     1 additional replica(s)
  S: dfa867e8b313ca93f525cb44fe97df8c1c5260f0 127.0.0.1:7007
     slots: (0 slots) slave
     replicates a2dbd1143d7e354bc48f84f11c738954582a73fb
  [OK] All nodes agree about slots configuration.
  >>> Check for open slots...
  >>> Check slots coverage...
  [ERR] Not all 16384 slots are covered by nodes.

  Fix using redis-trib.rb
  root@9b1f373fcb81:/redis/redis_work# /redis/redis-4.0.2/src/redis-trib.rb fix 127.0.0.1:7000
  ...
  ...
  <all missing slots are added now>
  root@9b1f373fcb81:/redis/redis_work# /redis/redis-4.0.2/src/redis-trib.rb check 127.0.0.1:7000
  ...
  ...
  [ERR] Nodes don't agree about configuration!
  >>> Check for open slots...
  >>> Check slots coverage...
  [OK] All 16384 slots covered.
  root@9b1f373fcb81:/redis/redis_work# /redis/redis-4.0.2/src/redis-cli -p 7000 cluster info | grep epoch
  cluster_current_epoch:10
  cluster_my_epoch:1
  root@9b1f373fcb81:/redis/redis_work# /redis/redis-4.0.2/src/redis-cli -p 7001 cluster info | grep epoch
  cluster_current_epoch:10
  cluster_my_epoch:2
  root@9b1f373fcb81:/redis/redis_work# /redis/redis-4.0.2/src/redis-cli -p 7002 cluster info | grep epoch
  Could not connect to Redis at 127.0.0.1:7002: Connection refused
  root@9b1f373fcb81:/redis/redis_work# /redis/redis-4.0.2/src/redis-cli -p 7003 cluster info | grep epoch
  cluster_current_epoch:10
  cluster_my_epoch:6
  root@9b1f373fcb81:/redis/redis_work# /redis/redis-4.0.2/src/redis-cli -p 7004 cluster info | grep epoch
  cluster_current_epoch:10
  cluster_my_epoch:7
  root@9b1f373fcb81:/redis/redis_work# /redis/redis-4.0.2/src/redis-cli -p 7005 cluster info | grep epoch
  cluster_current_epoch:10
  cluster_my_epoch:1
  root@9b1f373fcb81:/redis/redis_work# /redis/redis-4.0.2/src/redis-cli -p 7006 cluster info | grep epoch
  cluster_current_epoch:10
  cluster_my_epoch:2
  root@9b1f373fcb81:/redis/redis_work# /redis/redis-4.0.2/src/redis-cli -p 7007 cluster info | grep epoch
  cluster_current_epoch:10
  cluster_my_epoch:7
  root@9b1f373fcb81:/redis/redis_work# /redis/redis-4.0.2/src/redis-cli -p 7008 cluster info | grep epoch
  Could not connect to Redis at 127.0.0.1:7008: Connection refused
  root@9b1f373fcb81:/redis/redis_work# /redis/redis-4.0.2/src/redis-cli -p 7009 cluster info | grep epoch
  cluster_current_epoch:10
  cluster_my_epoch:6
  root@9b1f373fcb81:/redis/redis_work#
```

Comment: Similar open issue - https://github.com/antirez/redis/issues/3776

Answer (score 7):

If you are using recent version of Redis (I did in 6.0.6) and you are okay with loosing data on the master and salves that went down

`redis-cli --cluster fix ONE_OF_HEALTHY_NODE_IP:PORT --cluster-fix-with-unreachable-masters`

**Note**: It prompts with `Fix these slots by covering with a random node? (type 'yes' to accept):`

Answer (score 4):

Let me understand it again please. So, you have 5 masters + 5 slaves and your 1 master and its slaves go down, and are permanently down. You are ok with the data loss, and want to recover the cluster(or the part of it).
Basically you need to assign all the slots of the down nodes to the other nodes.

1. Stop all the existing servers(if you can).
2. In the nodes.conf file of
   each node, remove all references to the servers which are lost, and
   manually write down their slots in the other servers. Like if you
   have a healthy server S1 serving 0-1000 slots and another one S2
   serving 2001-3000 slots, and you lost 1001-2000 slots, you can
   assign S1 to have 0-1500 and S2 to have 1501-3000 slots.
3. Do the change in all the nodes.conf files
4. Start all the servers.

If it doesn't work, you may have to increase the epoch manually or act accordingly with the errors.

Another approach could be to set the property "cluster-require-full-coverage" to "no" on all the servers without stopping them. The cluster will be in ok status. After that, you can try to move the slots which are not in ok state using the cluster setslot command(please understand and go through its syntax well before running it).